# Launch an URL in Blackberry App

Tags: java, url, blackberry

How do I open, or launch, a URL from a BlackBerry application?  I am not interested in doing this through a browser, such as Opera.  I think there is a Java class called BrowserContentManager or similar, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: you want to make HTTP GET request to particular url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the demo code `BrowserContentManagerDemo.java` from the Blackberry JDE installation sample folder:
`BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0\samples\com\rim\samples\device\blackberry\browser\`

or from the Eclipse plugins folder:

`eclipse/plugins/net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29/components/samples/com/rim/samples/device/browser/browsercontentmanagerdemo/`

Comment: This class needs another 2 classes to work properly. Are http://code.google.com/p/eclipstest/source/browse/trunk/BrowserContentManagerDemo/src/com/rim/samples/device/blackberry/browser/?r=5

Comment: I removed the large section of code, for one it is copyrighted, and for another it's not useful on its own.  As Lobo points out, it requires supporting classes.  It is better just to point out where the sample code is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have already had an answer for BrowserContentmanager but I thought it worth mentioning that there is a similar api in JDE 5 and later called BrowserField.

Check this url for example code:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldConfig-class/ta-p/495716

Cheers

Ray